# Multiple Chrome users syncing with the same Google Account

Tags: google-chrome

I'm synching bookmarks etc. with Google Chrome across devices. Now I created a 2nd Chrome user (to have different bookmarks at work which still sync) but when I switch to that Chrome-user and try to login it says:

> This account is already used on the computer.

How can I get around this? I don't feel like creating a 2nd Google account for that purpose.

Comment: How do you create a 2nd Chrome user _without_ creating a 2nd Google account? If the two accounts are the same _person_ then maybe just have a separate "Work" folder for work-related bookmarks?

Comment: You can create multiple user-account in Chrome's settings. Having a seperate "Work" folder would be the easiest options but at work my browser-configuration and extensions are different. Also I don't want to merge passwords of both profiles etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to run **multiple Chrome profiles** if you want to use **one and the same Google account**.

Probably what you want is to run **multiple separate instances** of **Chrome**, since this would allow you to use **one and the same** **Google account**, therefore **sync all** the **bookmarks**, **extensions, settings** etc., but have **different logins**, for instance, on **Facebook** or any other **non Google websites** and **services**.

As of **2014-10-05**, the easiest way to run **multiple profiles, versions** or **instances** of **Chrome** is to use **Google Chrome Portable**, downloaded from:
http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Currently I'm running **4 separate instances** of **Google Chrome** *v37.0.2062.124*. **One instance is installed** and **three other instances** of **Google Chrome** are **portable**.

Here's how my Windows 7 Taskbar looks like when **all 4 instances** of **Chrome** are **opened and running**:

[image]

If you want to change **Google Chrom**e icon that is shown on the **Windows Taskbar** once **Google Chrome** is started, then you should follow this link:
[Is it possible to customize taskbar icons? If so how?](https://superuser.com/questions/613851/is-it-possible-to-customize-taskbar-icons-if-so-how)

The answer is given in comments: you need to change icons that are stored in **chrome.dll** using Resource Tuner (use Trial version) or Resource Hacker (free).

I've used **IcoFX** (Trial version) to generate various .ico icons.

The use of **multiple Chrome profiles** ***DOESN'T ALLOW*** to use one and the same **Google account**, running multiple separate Chrome instances ***DOES***.

**Good luck!**

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Chrome Canary? if not get Canary at http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html, then click the menu icon, go to options, Users. Delete that user which is labeled as "current", and sign in