# Is it possible to customize taskbar icons? If so how?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, taskbar, icons

I'd like to customize not just desktop icons but the icons that appear in the taskbar, is this possible?

And no, I'm not asking how to customize icons pinned to the taskbar, but rather the icons of active programs - specifically Chrome

There's not a single resource within the exe that contains the default icon, yet it continues to use the default icon

[image: Chrome icon]

Comment: Can you specify what version of windows.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28847/how-to-customize-your-windows-7-taskbar-icons-for-any-app/

Comment: Note that you can only change the icon on shortcuts, unless you manually edit the executable, which could cause signature checks to fail, and some programs may fail to elevate correctly. Not a good idea.

Comment: Hah, the funniest part is: chrome uses some hacks to add additional marks to icons: try creating second profile, and see what happens to icon (note: `Use small taskbar buttons` option have to be disabled)

Comment: Like there: http://imgur.com/UoRB1Uq
 Note: it's Comodo Dragon, treat it like custom chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Download and install [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).
2. Open ResHacker **as administrator** and click `File > Open` and choose the exe file.
3. Click on the `icon` folder then on one of the subfolders there and then on a file inside the subfolder
4. Right click on it and choose `Replace Resource...`
5. A dialog will appear, choose the icon you want to replace from the list on the right.
6. Click `Open file with new icon` and choose the icon you want.
7. Click `Replace`.
8. Click `File > Save`.

   - It has to be `as administrator` so it could write changes to files inside `program files`.
   - Note that ResHacker also renames the original file to `filename_original`.
   - If for some reason you can't write to Program Files, Just do a `Save As...`, save the exe file somewhere else and replace it later.

**Edit:** To summarize all the comments below - sometimes the application uses the resources of external dll (and theoratically, exe) file. So, if you change the icons in the exe and it's not working, check the application dll files and replace the icon there too.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the quicklaunch or how to change the icons of pinned programs. My question is in regard to the icons of active programs that appear in the taskbar.

Comment: @Gabardine, I think that perhaps you should clarify your request. perhaps an image.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize that. Anyways, it is not possible to change the program's (exe file) icon using Windows, since the icon is embedded in the exe file itself. You will need a tool like [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/) to actually changes the file's resources. ResEdit is free, check it out.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Check it out!

Comment: First I thought this was the answer but the damn thing keeps using the default icon even after I've replaced every sodding icon resource with the one I want

Comment: Try replacing again with [ResHacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) (sorry, I can't check it right now but..)

Comment: Alright, I have checked it and it works. I am editing my answer again :)

Comment: I've tried it now at least three times.

There's not a single resource within the exe that contains the default icon

Comment: Can you upload that exe file?

Comment: Here's the .exe: http://www.mediafire.com/download/wmbv4hfimu6l0nz/chrome.7z

Comment: Alright, [here's a step-by-step howto](http://imgur.com/a/g2Ppw#0) that I've uploaded. However, somtimes the exe's icon doesn't appear to be changed but when you open it the taskbar shows the right one.
Edit: If the old icon shows up, [rebuild the icon cache](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html).

Comment: Followed everything step by step, didn't work. Rebuilt the icon cache, still didn't work. I could edit the icon for foobar2000 but chrome won't let me no matter what.

Comment: I don't know what to say, since the pictures I've uploaded were about the very exe file that you have uploaded. What's the problem excatly? You can't find the icon inside ResHacker? You can't save? You can do all the steps but the old icon is still there?

Comment: Yes, the icon is still there: http://i.imgur.com/8OHJSax.png

Comment: Finally I found it. Chrome doesn't use the resources of the exe, but rather the resources of the chrome.dll in the [versionnumber] folder. So I replaced the resources of the .dll and now it works

Comment: Great! Was glad to help.
By the way, I didn't know that the icon was in the dll because it was in the exe too. I didn't have chrome installed so I couldn't think about this option.

Comment: Well you got me going on the right track if nothing else

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy:

1. Make a shortcut of the file on your desktop eg `myfile.txt` .
2. Then drag `myfile.txt` onto the taskbar where all the other little icons are.

You might already have to many so you can press the arrow next to the icons, find the `myfile.txt` icon and drag it back onto the toolbar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer doesn't help me since it only covers pinned icons.
I have nothing pinned to my taskbar and wish to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a tutorial on how to do this:

http://bendali.co.za/how-to-change-the-icon-of-a-program-in-windows/

I hope this is what you need.

Comment: Again, this is just how to change shortcut icons.