# Customise Chrome Taskbar Icon

Tags: google-chrome, taskbar, icons

I saw an answer about changing the Chrome icon when Chrome is running ([post](https://superuser.com/questions/613851/is-it-possible-to-customize-taskbar-icons-if-so-how))

I tried everything, I literally opened every file I could with Resource hacker and changed any icons I could find that had the Chrome icon and still nothing.

Comment: [Change taskbar icons of pinned programs](http://www.tenforums.com/customization/15861-change-taskbar-icons-pinned-programs.html)

Comment: Have you reboot or rebuilt the icon cache?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut for Google Chrome in any folder, change it's icon and pin it to the taskbar. If it is already pinned to the taskbar, you have to unpin it first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Chrome
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right click on its taskbar icon
3. Properties
4. Change Icon...
5. Browse
6. Choose the directory and the image file (must be a `.ico` file)
7. OK > OK

There is a delay in changing icons in the taskbar so you will need to wait a few minutes (or until the next system reboot) to see the selected icon appear.